# Outcome of my code

Tags: javascript

When I run my program, I get the expected output but I also receive the error:

> "Your function doesn't return the value"

Here is my code:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} 
//console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(userChoice,computerChoice){
    if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
        return "The result is a tie";
        }
    else{
        return "False" ;
    }   
 };
var pp = compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
console.log(pp);
```

Comment: What is this code written for?? what is expected output..??

Comment: You probably need to change the logic around else if(computerChoice <= 0.67)   cause I think you want to say else if(computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice <= 0.67)  ...?

Comment: [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wahwahwah/kLrjqatp/2/) seems to indicate that what you've posted is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} 
//console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(userChoice,computerChoice){
    if (userChoice == computerChoice) {
        return "The result is a tie";
    }
    return "False" ;

 };
var pp = compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
console.log(pp);
```